# pear commands not working

Tags: macos, homebrew, pear

I recently installed pear via homebrew by

```
brew install homebrew/science/pear
```

but when I try to run any commands with pear, all I get is the intro screen which lists all the command types. It seems like the command line is not recognizing anything after "pear". I tested this by running

```
pear <channel-discover phpseclib.sourceforge.net>
```

and got

```
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

which I believe affirms my hypothesis that everything after "pear" is ignored.

Is there any way to fix this? Or am I not entering in the commands correctly? I'm new to pear so I wouldn't know.

Comment: Are you really having the `<` and `>` in your command? Remove them.

Comment: no I didn't have those in the first try of a command. I just did it because it was a way to check if it even recognized any command. I solved this problem though by uninstalling via homebrew and installing via curl. I think the homebrew version is bugged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to uninstall via homebrew and reinstall via curl. I think the homebrew version was bugged for me.